# Implementing Matrix Addition and Multiplication in SYCL

Tags: sycl

I am trying to implement both matrix addition and multiplication in sycl within a single program but i am getting an error on addition part[no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const]. I dont know the reason of error. It would be great help if someone and tell me the reason. Thanks

I have implemented both Addition and Multiplication separately and it works. I think the reason is that i am using template for multiplication and it is giving problem for addition part

```
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cl::sycl;

class mxm_kernel;

void display_matrix(float* m, int matSize) {
if (matSize > 16) {
    return;
}

std::cout << "=======" << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matSize; j++) {
        std::cout << m[i * matSize + j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "=======" << std::endl;
;
}

inline int prevPowerOfTwo(int x) {
if (x < 0) {
    return 0;
}
--x;
x |= x >> 1;
x |= x >> 2;
x |= x >> 4;
x |= x >> 8;
x |= x >> 16;
return x - (x >> 1);
}

inline bool isPowerOfTwo(int x) {
return (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
}

template <typename T>
bool local_mxm(cl::sycl::queue& q, T* MA, T* MB, T* MC, T* MD, int matSize) {
// Make sure it is power of two before running
if (!isPowerOfTwo(matSize)) {
    std::cout << " This example only works with power of two sizes "
        << std::endl;
    return true;
}

auto device = q.get_device();
auto maxBlockSize =
    device.get_info<cl::sycl::info::device::max_work_group_size>();
auto blockSize = prevPowerOfTwo(std::sqrt(maxBlockSize));
std::cout << " The Device Max Work Group Size is : " << maxBlockSize
    << std::endl;
std::cout << " The order is : " << matSize << std::endl;
std::cout << " The blockSize is : " << blockSize << std::endl;
// Make sure the block size is not larger than the mat size
blockSize = std::min(matSize, blockSize);

{
    range<1> dimensions(matSize * matSize);
    const property_list props = { property::buffer::use_host_ptr() };
    buffer<T> bA(MA, dimensions, props);
    buffer<T> bB(MB, dimensions, props);
    buffer<T> bC(MC, dimensions, props);
    buffer<T> bD(MD, dimensions, props);

    q.submit([&](handler& cgh) {
        auto pA = bA.template get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
        auto pB = bB.template get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
        auto pC = bC.template get_access<access::mode::write>(cgh);
        auto pD = bD.template get_access<access::mode::write>(cgh);
        auto localRange = range<1>(blockSize * blockSize);

        accessor<T, 1, access::mode::read_write, access::target::local> pBA(
            localRange, cgh);
        accessor<T, 1, access::mode::read_write, access::target::local> pBB(
            localRange, cgh);

        cgh.parallel_for<class matrix_add>(range<2> {matSize, matSize}, [=](id<2> it) {
            pD[it] = pA[it] + pB[it];
        });

        cgh.parallel_for<mxm_kernel>(
            nd_range<2>{range<2>(matSize, matSize),
            range<2>(blockSize, blockSize)},
            [=](nd_item<2> it) {
            // Current block
            int blockX = it.get_group(0);
            int blockY = it.get_group(1);

            // Current local item
            int localX = it.get_local_id(0);
            int localY = it.get_local_id(1);

            // Start in the A matrix
            int a_start = matSize * blockSize * blockY;
            // End in the b matrix
            int a_end = a_start + matSize - 1;
            // Start in the b matrix
            int b_start = blockSize * blockX;

            // Result for the current C(i,j) element
            T tmp = 0.0f;
            // We go through all a, b blocks
            for (int a = a_start, b = b_start; a <= a_end;
                a += blockSize, b += (blockSize * matSize)) {
                // Copy the values in shared memory collectively
                pBA[localY * blockSize + localX] =
                    pA[a + matSize * localY + localX];
                // Note the swap of X/Y to maintain contiguous access
                pBB[localX * blockSize + localY] =
                    pB[b + matSize * localY + localX];
                it.barrier(access::fence_space::local_space);
                // Now each thread adds the value of its sum
                for (int k = 0; k < blockSize; k++) {
                    tmp +=
                        pBA[localY * blockSize + k] * pBB[localX * blockSize + k];
                }
                // The barrier ensures that all threads have written to local
                // memory before continuing
                it.barrier(access::fence_space::local_space);
            }
            auto elemIndex = it.get_global_id(1) * it.get_global_range()[0] +
                it.get_global_id(0);
            // Each thread updates its position
            pC[elemIndex] = tmp;
        });
    });
}
return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
float* MA;
float* MB;
float* MC;
float* MD;
bool sycl = true;
bool error = false;

int matSize = 4;
MA = new float[matSize * matSize];
MB = new float[matSize * matSize];
MC = new float[matSize * matSize];
MD = new float[matSize * matSize];



std::cout << " Input matrix " << std::endl;
display_matrix(MA, matSize);
display_matrix(MB, matSize);
display_matrix(MC, matSize);
display_matrix(MD, matSize);



if (sycl) {
    std::cout << " ***** SYCL " << std::endl;
    // MatrixC initialization
    std::cout << "MATRIX D" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matSize; j++) {
            MD[i * matSize + j] = 0.0f;  // i * matSize + j;
            std::cout << MD[i * matSize + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "=======" << std::endl;
    // MatrixC initialization
    std::cout << "MATRIX C" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matSize; j++) {
            MC[i * matSize + j] = 0.0f;  // i * matSize + j;
            std::cout << MC[i * matSize + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "=======" << std::endl;
    // MatrixA initialization
    std::cout << "MATRIX A" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matSize; j++) {
            MA[i * matSize + j] = 0.0f + j;  // i * matSize + j;
            std::cout << MA[i * matSize + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "=======" << std::endl;
    // MatrixB initialization
    std::cout << "MATRIX B" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < matSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matSize; j++) {
            MB[i * matSize + j] = 0.0f + j;  // i * matSize + j;
            std::cout << MB[i * matSize + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "=======" << std::endl;
    {
        {
            cpu_selector device_selector;
            queue q(device_selector);


            auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            error = local_mxm(q, MA, MB, MC, MD, matSize);
            q.wait_and_throw();
            auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            auto time =
                std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start)
                .count();
            std::cout << "SYCL: ";
            std::cout << "Time: " << time << std::endl;
            float flops =
                (2.0f * matSize * matSize * matSize / (time / 1000.0f)) * 1.0e-9f;
            std::cout << "GFLOPs: " << flops << std::endl;
            std::cout << " Output " << std::endl;
        }
        display_matrix(MC, matSize);
        display_matrix(MD, matSize);
    }
}

delete[] MA;
delete[] MB;
delete[] MC;

return error ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the `parallel_for` invocations that you have in your "combined" function are both inside a single command group submission which is something that SYCL doesn't allow. One command group (`queue::submit(command_group_handler)`) scope only handles one kernel in its body. Therefore, you have to split your `parallel_for`s into two separate queue submissions. And just to make sure what I am saying is clear enough and aligns with your intensions, **yes**, you can keep them in the same function scope, i.e.:

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool local_mxm(cl::sycl::queue& q, T* MA, T* MB, T* MC, T* MD, int matSize) {
  ...
  // Command group submission for the matrix addition kernel
  ...
  // Command group submission for the matrix multiplication kernel
  ...
}
```

**Matrix Addition**
Command group submission for the matrix addition kernel. Here's how your `matrix_add` submission would look like:

```cpp
q.submit([&](handler& cgh) {
  auto pA = bA.template get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
  auto pB = bB.template get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
  // You don't need accessor (pC) to the buffer (bC) anymore
  auto pD = bD.template get_access<access::mode::write>(cgh);

  cgh.parallel_for<matrix_add>(
      range<1>{static_cast<size_t>(matSize * matSize)},
      [=](id<1> it) { pD[it] = pA[it] + pB[it]; });
});
```

Now, notice how I have removed the `class` keyword before `matrix_add` when passed as a template argument to parallel_for. This is because you are (as of SYCL 1.2.1) required to forward declare your kernel classes or define them as function objects if you prefer but you cannot derive them on the go. The compiler also needs the kernel names to be unique, thus it is recommended that you do the latter if you're going to have multiple calls of your those kernels in your program.

Next up are the messed-up ranges or index space (in OpenCL, *NDRange* refers to the **index space** of the input data for data-parallel applications).

The reason that in the matrix multiplication code (which should be from our samples in [computecpp-sdk](https://github.com/codeplaysoftware/computecpp-sdk/tree/master/samples)) the index space is of `nd_range<2>` with `nd_item<2>` (info about the work-items/groups IDs and sizes) is so that the blocked (or tiled) matrix multiplication algorithm can be implemented but all accessors are 1D. The correct positions are derived through some tricky pointer arithmetic, but anyway, by no means you could do the following:

```cpp
// !kinda pseudo-code, so don't take it literally
accessor<T, 1> acc(...);
parallel_for<kernel>(range<2>{size,size}, [=](id<2> i) {
  acc[i] = i;
}
```

What you would normally do is the following:

```cpp
// !kinda pseudo-code, so don't take it literally
accessor<T, 1> acc(...);
parallel_for<kernel>(range<1>{size * size}, [=](id<1> i) {
  acc[i] = i;
}
```

This is because you wanna directly access the linear id of the internal pointer in the matrix addition case.
And if your input arrays were 2D, you'd do the opposite: `range<2>{size,size}, [=](id<2> i)`

---

**Matrix Multiplication**
Command group submission for the matrix multiplication kernel stays the same as it was in the original code.

```cpp
q.submit([&](handler& cgh) {
  auto pA = bA.template get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
  auto pB = bB.template get_access<access::mode::read>(cgh);
  auto pC = bC.template get_access<access::mode::write>(cgh);
  auto pD = bD.template get_access<access::mode::write>(cgh);
  auto localRange = range<1>(blockSize * blockSize);

  accessor<T, 1, access::mode::read_write, access::target::local> pBA(
      localRange, cgh);
  accessor<T, 1, access::mode::read_write, access::target::local> pBB(
      localRange, cgh);

 cgh.parallel_for<mxm_kernel>(
      nd_range<2>{range<2>(static_cast<size_t>(matSize),
                           static_cast<size_t>(matSize)),
                  range<2>(blockSize, blockSize)}, 
      [=](nd_item<2> it) {
        ... 
      });
});
```

Try and read up the blocked matrix multiplication code and maybe look up some resources explaining the algorithm. It is quite a tricky one but I can imagine there's some decent explanation on it. (maybe in the CUDA learning materials).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining it in such detail it was really helpful. I had found out the problem of using a single command group for both and rectified it, but i messed up their ranges and missed the class point that you mentioned. I will make these changes. Thanks

Comment: You could use hierarchical parallelism instead of using low-level constructs such as barriers.

Comment: @RonanKeryell is correct here. 
Hierarchical parallelism is possible in SYCL and provides for a cleaner and easier to understand the structure of your kernels. Synchronisation primitives such as work-group barriers will be implicitly placed for you.